# Authorizing an API call with Keycloak always returns AcessDenied - Blazor C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, keycloak, policy

My goal is to restrain API access based on policies and their requirements. I'm doing this in a Blazor App, therefore I have a client side and server side.

I can easily access the user's data in my client side and check for their roles, but for some reason, I feel like my server side doesn't actually have this data. So, how will it be able to do the checking (if user has a role, or if user's username equal this) if it doesn't know user's details?

In my controller, I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "Developer")]
public String GetController()
{
    return "You have reached this API";
}
```

In `ConfigureServices`, I have:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("Developer", policy => policy.RequiredUserName("developer"));
);
```

I'm wondering how will my server side know about user's username, where and when will it retrieve this data? I'm just receiving `AcessDenied` when I try to access this API.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I find out that instead of using `policy.RequiredUserName("developer")`. I need to use `policy.RequiredClaim("preferred username", "developer")`. However, I still can't access roles. I took a look at the data inside `ClaimsPrincipal` in server side, and I've got some claims but not roles in there. What is very weird, because, as an example, I'm displaying `User.IsInRole('developer')` in the client, which is returning `True` but when I try to do the same thing in the server side, it returns `False`.

Why my client side has more data than my server? As a matter of fact, I'm Injecting `AuthenticationStateProvider` in my client and only accessing `AuthenticationState` in my server. (I've tried to inject the first, but it is just creating a null object).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out where I was sinning. The roles were not in `scope` so I needed to add them in `ConfigureServices`, more specifically where I was adding the `OpenIDConnect`.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
...
options.Scope.Add("roles_list");
});
```